# Trying to delete nodes from a linked list using id variable. In c

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to delete nodes from my linked list. The list gets populated from a file when the program loads.

The problem is that when I run the delete function and input the id which I want deleted the program stops and gets stuck. It does not crash, it just does nothing.

I've ran the debug on it and it passes the right data to the function. The temp variable seems to have an issue and only has junk value.

Originally I didn't use `malloc` but even with `malloc` it still didn't work.

```
void main() {
    initLinkList();
    loadFile();

    do{
        menu();
        switch (userChoice){
        case 1:
            add();
            userChoice = NULL;
            break;
        case 2:
            printNodes();
            userChoice = NULL;
            break;
        case 3:
            deleteNode();
            userChoice = NULL;
            break;
        case 4:
            deleteNode();
            userChoice = NULL;
            break;
        }
    } while (userChoice != -1);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("pause");
}

void deleteNode() {
    int empId = 0;
    char empFirstName[15];

    do {
        deleteMenu();
        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter The ID of the person you want to delete\n");
            scanf("%d", &empId);
            listHead = deleteByID(listHead, empId);
            userChoice = NULL;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter The First Name of the person you want to delete\n");
            scanf("%s", empFirstName);
            listHead = deleteByName(listHead, empFirstName);
            userChoice = NULL;
            break;
        }
    } while (userChoice != -1);
} 

CONT *deleteByID(CONT *head, int num) {
    CONT *temp1, *ptr;
    //temp1 = (struct contact*)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    //ptr = (struct contact*)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    if (head->employeeId == num) {
       temp1 = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(temp1);
       return head;
    }
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr->next != NULL) {
        if (ptr->next->employeeId == num) {
            temp1 = ptr->next;
            temp1->next = ptr->next;
            free(temp1);
            return head;
        } //end if 
    } //end while
    printf("%d not present in the list\n", num);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: You don't advance `ptr` in your loop to search a node with the id. The last statement in the body of the while loop should be `ptr = ptr->next`. (It's also clumsy to access everything via `ptr->next`. Why not use just `ptr` and initialise it with ´head->next`?)

Comment: Oh, and there's no need to `malloc` resources for pointers that point into existing memory, like a temporary pointer that traverses the list. `malloc` is useful when you need to create a handle to a new object or to an array of dynamic size.

Comment: there are lots of examples on stackoverflow of how to delete a node from a linked list,  suggest a bit of searching/googling to find plenty of examples

Comment: @user3629249 I wouldn't be asking if i didn't look and research other places. Why bother answering if that's all you have.

Comment: There are many happy to help, but no one can help you unless you post a verifiable example. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." For example how was `listHead` declared, initialized and populated? That's just one example. That's why we need a full verifiable example.

Comment: void initLinkList(){
          
             listHead = (struct contact *)malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
             listHead->next = NULL;
                  } 

           CONT * initLinkList_new(CONT *head){
         // set head
         listHead = head;
         listHead->next = NULL;
         return listHead;
                } // initLinkList

               void addEmployeeToEnd(CONT *head, CONT *current){
      CONT *tmp = head;
      while (tmp->next != NULL){
             tmp = tmp->next;
       }
       tmp->next = current;
             }//read the file